# Regex error on Java

Tags: java, regex

I created regex for extracting php exception message fields

`(\w+.*)|\G(?!\A)\s*#\d+\s+(\S+\.php)\((\d+)\):\s(\w+.*)#012|#\d+\s{(\w+)}`

Demo Links : https://regex101.com/r/xI6cR0/2

Error Message:

Illegal repetition near index 66 `(\w+.*)|\G(?!\A)\s*#\d+\s+(\S+\.php)\((\d+)\):\s(\w+.*)#012|#\d+\s{(\w+)}` ^

Comment: Can I convert it to Java compatible regex?

Comment: Java Code : https://ideone.com/8VgujM .

You can test java regex on : http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape all `\` again by `\\` for it to work.So your `\w` would become `\\w`.You also need to escape `{}`.So it would be

```
(\\w+.*)|\\G(?!\\A)\\s*#\\d+\\s+(\\S+\\.php)\\((\\d+)\\):\\s(\\w+.*)#012|#\\d+\\s\\{(\\w+)\\}
```

Comment: @Amit you need to escape `{}` as well

Comment: Thanks @vks, Working fine for me

Comment: If the backslashes were the problem, the *Java* compiler would have thrown the exception, not the regex compiler.

Comment: @AlanMoore `{}` was the real culprit as it means `repition` in regex